# UFT API Test Como puedo extraer y guardar valores en XLS de un XML response?

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo usando UFT API Test, y necesito extraer ciertos valores de un XML Response y salvarlos en un archivo XLS ya existente, que serán datos de entrada para un GUI Test. Este es mi XML Response:

```
<NS1:Body>
  <NS3:BuscaSaldosCaptacionOut xmlns:NS3="http://www.portal.com/ws/esb/ConsultaCuentasSaldos">
 <SaldosCaptacion>
    <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
    <Cuenta>0201484326</Cuenta>
    <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
    <SubProductoCuenta>0382</SubProductoCuenta>
    <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
    <IdCuenta>0201484326</IdCuenta>
    <SaldoInicialDia>7062.42</SaldoInicialDia>
    <SaldoPromedio>30596.01</SaldoPromedio>
    <SaldoActual>17062.42</SaldoActual>
    <SaldoDisponible>17062.42</SaldoDisponible>
    <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
 </SaldosCaptacion>
 <SaldosCaptacion>
    <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
    <Cuenta>0201484371</Cuenta>
    <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
    <SubProductoCuenta>0340</SubProductoCuenta>
    <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
    <SaldoInicialDia>6825.11</SaldoInicialDia>
    <SaldoPromedio>8936.26</SaldoPromedio>
    <SaldoActual>6825.11</SaldoActual>
    <SaldoDisponible>6825.11</SaldoDisponible>
    <SaldoRetenido>0.00</SaldoRetenido>
    <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
 </SaldosCaptacion>
 <SaldosCaptacion>
    <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
    <Cuenta>0201533729</Cuenta>
    <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
    <SubProductoCuenta>0363</SubProductoCuenta>
    <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
    <SaldoInicialDia>28316.52</SaldoInicialDia>
    <SaldoPromedio>6230.52</SaldoPromedio>
    <SaldoActual>7374.52</SaldoActual>
    <SaldoDisponible>7374.52</SaldoDisponible>
    <SaldoRetenido>942.00</SaldoRetenido>
    <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
 </SaldosCaptacion>
```

Necesito guardar los valores de "Cuenta" y "SaldoActual" (Todos) en un XLS ya existente.
"Write to file" no me funciona.